# Woocommercee Store API's response mixed with HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, postman, woocommerce-rest-api

So I'm maintaining an app with Wordpress and Woocommercee as backend.
Problem is when I hit **add item API** it returned not only JSON like always, but also HTML which not occured on previous version of Woocommercee.

Endpoint `/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item`

Response

```
        <div class="row section-checkout-step">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul>
                    <li class="step-1"><span class="step-name"><span><span class="step-num">01</span><span>Shopping Cart</span></span></span>
                    </li><li class="step-2"><span class="step-name"><span><span class="step-num">02</span><span>Check out</span></span></span>
                    </li><li class="step-3"><span class="step-name"><span><span class="step-num">03</span><span>Order completed</span></span></span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
{"coupons":[],"shipping_rates":[{"package_id":0,"name":"Shipment 1","destination":{"address_1":"","address_2":"","city":""
.............
```

[image: screenshot of Postman's response]

[image: other screenshot]

I'm expecting only JSON got returned, without the HTML part.

I'm already trying to search in woocommercee plugin file but can't find the source of problem.

I'm not using any of 'multi-step' plugin.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Sure looks like it was added by some multi-step plugin though (and probably one that hooks into the wrong thing, or doesn't check the environment properly - because in the Rest API context, returning this can hardly make any sense) ... I'd first of all try and search the code base for that div class, `section-checkout-step`, and see in what context that gets found.